# Settings variables through a method

Tags: c#

I have variables that I want to set through a method.

```
string size
double sizeprice
```

This is the code

```
    public static void PizzaSizeUI(int choice, string size, double sizeprice, bool Quit){
        Console.WriteLine("Size");
        Console.WriteLine("1.Small");
        Console.WriteLine("2.Medium");
        Console.WriteLine("3.Large");

        //To Check if Int is entered, If a character / string is entered, program doesn't crash.
        while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out choice))
        {
            break;
        }


        if (choice == 1)
        {
            size = "Small";
            sizeprice = 5.00;
            Quit = true;
        }
        else if (choice == 2)
        {
            size = "Medium";
            sizeprice = 7.00;
            Quit = true;
        }
        else if (choice == 3)
        {
            size = "Large";
            sizeprice = 10.00;
            Quit = true;
        }




    }
```

This is where the method is called

```
PizzaSizeUI(choice, size, sizeprice, Quit);
```

I've printed the values that came from the method itself, and they have been set, but the outside values are still set as they were, "Not Chosen" and 0. 
How do I set the variables through the method?

Answer (score 3):

You are just changing the values inside the method. You are not giving a 'pointer' to the variables, instead it copies them (or their references are copied, depending on the type).

In order to make this work, you should pass the variables in using `ref`, or if there are only for output, you should mark them `out`:

```
public static void PizzaSizeUI(out int choice, out string size, out double sizeprice, out bool Quit){
```

And call them with `out` too:

```
int choice;
string size;
double sizeprice;
bool Quit;
PizzaSizeUI(out choice, out size, out sizeprice, out Quit);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is an example of several code smells in one small piece.

1. Using `if` when you should use `case`
2. Calling a `void` method but expect the results back (read more on CQS)
3. Combining "UI" with logic
4. Expecting value types to be used as reference types

At least, your method should **return** something in order for you to get the result. Some might suggest using `ref` or `out` value typed parameters but I *strongly discourage* you from doing that.

Instead, you need to create something like this:

```
public enum PizzaSize
{
    Small,
    Medium,
    Large
}

public struct PizzaDetails
{
    public PizzaDetails(int choice, PizzaSize size, double price)
    {
        Choice = choice;
        Size = size;
        Price = price;
    }

    int Choice { get; set; }
    PizzaSize Size { get; set; }
    double Price { get; set; }
}

public class PizzaChoice
{
    public PizzaDetails GetPizzaDetails(int choice)
    {
        switch (choice)
        {
            case 1:
                return new PizzaDetails(choice, PizzaSize.Small, 5);
            case 2:
                return new PizzaDetails(choice, PizzaSize.Medium, 7);
            case 3:
                return new PizzaDetails(choice, PizzaSize.Large, 10);
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Invalid choice", nameof(choice));
        }
    }
}
```